# FreeMarker jar conflicting issues

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, jbpm

I have added new Mail Temlating functionality in my module. I used FTL Templates for the same.Current application is using Spring MVC,jBPM APIs,Tomcat.
But when I tried to run the project it will give me following exception.

```
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.internalTrigger(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:38)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:56)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:89)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:124)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:205)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:164)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(ExtendedNodeInstanceImpl.java:47)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:162)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StateBasedNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StateBasedNodeInstance.java:143)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:239)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.HumanTaskNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(HumanTaskNodeInstance.java:90)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.workItemCompleted(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:301)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.signalEvent(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:277)
 at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.signalEvent(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:326)
 at org.drools.persistence.jpa.processinstance.JPAWorkItemManager.completeWorkItem(JPAWorkItemManager.java:121)
 at org.drools.command.runtime.process.CompleteWorkItemCommand.execute(CompleteWorkItemCommand.java:69)
 at org.drools.command.runtime.process.CompleteWorkItemCommand.execute(CompleteWorkItemCommand.java:32)
 at org.drools.command.impl.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:36)
 at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.execute(SingleSessionCommandService.java:367)
 at org.drools.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession$1.completeWorkItem(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:150)
 at org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler$GetResultContentResponseHandler.execute(CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler.java:364)
 at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskClientHandler.messageReceived(TaskClientHandler.java:153)
 at org.jbpm.task.service.mina.MinaTaskClientHandler.messageReceived(MinaTaskClientHandler.java:47)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:713)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:793)
 at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:375)
 at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:229)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:793)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:119)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
 at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:426)
 at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:638)
 at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:598)
 at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:587)
 at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:61)
 at    org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:969)
 at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 57 more
```

How to find conflicts in this ?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a conflict. It just seems like log4j is missing in the classpath.

Comment: Just make sure that you add log4j in your class path

Comment: its already there in my classpath.....

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
 at freemarker.log._Log4JLoggerFactory.getLogger(_Log4JLoggerFactory.java:67)
 at freemarker.log.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:284)
 at freemarker.template.utility.SecurityUtilities.<clinit>(SecurityUtilities.java:66)
 at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.<clinit>(BeansWrapper.java:147)
 at freemarker.template.ObjectWrapper.<clinit>(ObjectWrapper.java:81)
 at freemarker.core.Configurable.<init>(Configurable.java:161)
 at freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:195)